# ngx-accordion with webpack says Error: expected expression, got '<'

Tags: angular, webpack, accordion

I have installed ngx-accordion using command

```
npm install ngx-accordion --save
```

I'm using webpack and in my app.module.ts I am importing it like

```
import { AccordionModule } from "ngx-accordion";
```

and then in this file I have added AccordionModule in imports array

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        NgbModule.forRoot(),        
        NgxDatatableModule,       
        routing,
        AccordionModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        MenuItem,
        ManageUsers,
        AddUser,

    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    entryComponents: [
        AddUser,        
    ],
    providers: [ApiService, ListDocumentService, UtilHelper, FilterPipe]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Now it should be all set as per configuration [here](https://github.com/pleerock/ngx-accordion)

when I run application I see following

```
Error: expected expression, got '<'
  Evaluating http://localhost:62910/ngx-accordion
  Evaluating http://localhost:62910/app/app.module.js
  Evaluating http://localhost:62910/app/main.js
  Loading app
Stack trace:
evaluate@http://localhost:62910/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:2822:8
translateAndInstantiate/</<@http://localhost:62910/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3623:21
dynamicExecute@http://localhost:62910/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:1145:18
doEvaluate@http://localhost:62910/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:1092:13
ensureEvaluate@http://localhost:62910/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:1000:13
makeDynamicRequire/<@http://localhost:62910/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:1018:20
@http://localhost:62910/app/app.module.js:92:23
@http://localhost:62910/app/app.module.js:1:31
@http://localhost:62910/app/app.module.js:1:2
```

How should I get it fixed? looks like its looking for file which does not exist and its finding index file which starts with '<'
webpack should be able to handle as it does with ngx-datatable